# Is there a way to batch change the time?

Tags: php, mysql

there are two columns as the following in my mysql database:

```
ID        time
1          2012-02-05 14:15:54
2          2012-02-05 14:15:54
3          2012-02-05 14:15:54
4         2012-02-05 14:15:54
5          2012-02-05 14:15:54
10         2012-02-05 14:15:54
```

Now,i want to use a sql command(using in phpmyadmin) to update the time which is Optional in `(2011-01-05 14:15:54 ---2012-04-05 14:15:54)`

i want to change this `2012-02-05 14:15:54`  to another time which is in  `(2011-01-05 14:15:54 ---2012-04-05 14:15:54)` eg:`2011-02-06 13:15:54  2011-05-06 11:15:54....`

Comment: Ha, I wish. I'd be in 5 years ago right now...

Comment: Time may change me....But you can't change time.

Comment: do you want to forward all the values with some months or years? what do you ask for?

Comment: generate a new time randly which between (2011-01-05 14:15:54 ---2012-04-05 14:15:54) then replace the old time in time column

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want?

```
UPDATE your_table 
  SET time = DATE_SUB(time, INTERVAL 5 YEAR) 
  WHERE time BETWEEN '2011-01-05 14:15:54' AND '2012-01-05 14:15:54'
```

Comment: i am sorry. i put your code in phpmyadmin, it doesn't change the time

Comment: @37336792 answer the comments asked in your question